# How can I make a String buffer in the form of a table

Tags: java, string, pdf, itext

I am working on report application in which contact information need to be shown on page header such that if information is more it appears on next column right aligned like a table.
For eg:- Suppose contact information contains 5 rows (A,B,C,D,E) and only 3 rows are allowed at page header ti will be shown like this:-

A  D
B  E

C

observe that D and E comes on next line. But now A, B, C is of random length and my String buffer needs to be made in the form of table or in rows and columns. To make cols

1.) I changed the contact information into 2D array.
2.) Take the cols and find the largest width of contents from that column
3.) Add spaces to each column row so that next column will look right aligned.

For 2nd step I had taken the width of particular string using BaseFont
        double w = bf.getWidthPoint(s, size);

After maximum width is found this width is taken as the largest one then I subtract

add space = largest width - width of (A) to A

Similarly, add space = largest width - width of (B) to B

so that D and E will be right aligned.

But I didn't find a way to give

--> spaces = above width calculated with bf

so that while printing on pdfs it appears like a table.

Following is the sample code:-

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class PrintSpacePdf {
    private static String arrNames[] = { "US Rates Strategy Cash",
            "Pavan Wadhwa(1-212) 844-4597", "Srini Ramaswamy(1-212) 844-4983",
            "Meera Chandan(1-212) 855-4555", "Kimberly Harano(1-212) 823-4996",
            "Feng Deng(1-212) 855-2555", "US Rates Strategy Derivatives",
            "Srini Ramaswamy(1-212) 811-4999",
            "Alberto Iglesias(1-212) 898-5442",
            "Praveen Korapaty(1-212) 812-3444", "Feng Deng(1-212) 812-2456",
            "US Rates Strategy Derivatives", "Srini Ramaswamy(1-212) 822-4999",
            "Alberto Iglesias(1-212) 822-5098",
            "Praveen Korapaty(1-212) 812-3655", "Feng Deng(1-212) 899-2222" };
    private static int SIZE = arrNames.length;
    private static int maxRows = 0;
    private static int maxCols = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        writeStringToPDF(generateBuffer(), 500, 400, "C://barchart.pdf");
        // writeChartToPDF(generatePieChart(), 500, 400, "C://piechart.pdf");
    }

    public static String generateBuffer() {
        maxRows = 5;
        maxCols = (SIZE % maxRows == 0) ? SIZE / maxRows : (SIZE / maxRows) + 1;
        int size = 5;// fontSize
        BaseFont bf;
        String buffer = null;
        try {
            bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252,
                    BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

            System.out.println("rows:" + maxRows + "cols:" + maxCols);

            String arrData[][] = initializeTableArrays(arrNames);

            // showArrayData(arrData);

            arrData = addSpacesToArrayContents(arrData, size, bf);

            buffer = createBufferWithTableArray(arrData);
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    public static String createBufferWithTableArray(String[][] arrData) {
        String buffer = "";
        for (int r = 0; r < maxRows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < maxCols; c++) {
                if (arrData[r][c] != null) {
                    buffer += arrData[r][c];
                }
            }
            buffer += "\n";
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    public static String[][] initializeTableArrays(String arrNames[]) {
        String arrData[][] = new String[maxRows][maxCols];
        int col = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrNames.length; i++) {
            if (arrNames[i] != null) {
                col = 0;
                for (int j = i; j < arrNames.length; j += maxRows) {
                    // System.out.println("i:" + i + "col" + col + "j:" + j);
                    if (arrNames[j] != null) {
                        arrData[i][col] = arrNames[j].trim();
                        arrNames[j] = null;
                    }
                    col++;
                }
            }
        }
        return arrData;
    }

    public static String[][] addSpacesToArrayContents(String arrData[][],
            int size, BaseFont bf) {
        for (int cols = 0; cols < maxCols; cols++) {
            double maxWidth = getMaximumColWidth(arrData, cols, size, bf);

            for (int rows = 0; rows < maxRows; rows++) {
                String s = arrData[rows][cols];
                if (s != null) {
                    double w = bf.getWidthPoint(s, size);
                    double noOfSpaces = maxWidth - w;
                    arrData[rows][cols] = addSpaces(s, noOfSpaces);
                }
            }
        }
        return arrData;
    }

    public static double getMaximumColWidth(String[][] arrData, int column,
            int size, BaseFont bf) {
        double maxSize = 0;
        for (int cols = 0; cols < maxCols; cols++) {
            for (int rows = 0; rows < maxRows; rows++) {
                String s = arrData[rows][cols];
                if (s != null) {
                    double w = bf.getWidthPoint(s, size);
                    maxSize = (maxSize < w) ? w : maxSize;
                }

            }
        }
        return (maxSize);
    }

    public static String addSpaces(String s, double noOfSpaces) {
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfSpaces; i++) {
            s = s.concat(" ");
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static void showArrayData(String arrData[][]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
            String inner[] = arrData[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < inner.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("i:" + i + "j:" + j + "->" + inner[j]);
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
    }

    public static void writeStringToPDF(String buffer, int width, int height,
            String fileName) {
        PdfWriter writer = null;

        Document document = new Document();

        try {
            writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
                    fileName));
            document.open();
            PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
            System.out.println(buffer);
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN,BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            contentByte.beginText();
            contentByte.setFontAndSize(bf, 5);
            contentByte.showText(buffer);
            contentByte.endText();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        document.close();
    }

}
```

Please help us show contacts in the string buffer which is equivalent to a table using above approach.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)), for this purpose. You can try it as an output using a simple `System.out.format("%-(MAXWIDTH)s%n", textToDisplay);`, that will print the value for you to look at, if this is what you desired. Now to find the `MAXWIDTH`, you can iterate over `arrNames` and see whose `arrNames[index].length()` is the largest, that will be your width for a column.

Comment: The code sample you provide is all wrong. The `showText()` method adds a text string to the direct content without any formatting, even without breaking the line at the end of the page. Why aren't you using any of the high-level objects to create a table?